# Daily updates feature of Actions on Google throws UnparseableJsonResponse API Version 2 error

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

While using Daily updates feature of Actions on Google I am getting the following error:

```
UnparseableJsonResponse
API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: ": Cannot find field.".
```

I have 4 intents:-

1. show-daily-offer: The additional triggering intent
2. daily-update-suggestion: This intent shows a suggestion chip with the text "Receive daily offers"

3.

configure-daily-updates: This intent has "Receive daily offers" in the User says section and action_intent_CONFIGURE_UPDATES  in the Events section and the following custom payload:

```
{
  "google": {
    "system_intent": {
      "intent": "actions.intent.REGISTER_UPDATE",
      "data": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.RegisterUpdateValueSpec",
        "intent": "show-daily-offer",
        "updateContextValueSpec": {
          "timeContext": {
            "frequency": "DAILY"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4. finish-daily-updates: This intent has actions_intent_REGISTER_UPDATE  in the events section.

However when I click on the suggestion the 'configure-daily-updates' gets called but throws the error:

UnparseableJsonResponse
API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: ": Cannot find field.".

Answer (score 0):

Update your custom payload to this:

```
         {
          "google": {
            "system_intent": {
              "intent": "actions.intent.REGISTER_UPDATE",
              "data": {
                "@type":
                     "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.RegisterUpdateValueSpec",
                "intent": "show-daily-offer",
                "triggerContext": { "timeContext": { "frequency": "DAILY" } }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

"triggerContext" instead of "updateContextValueSpec"

I made the correction to the documentation. The updated documentation should be available in a few days.

**I currently work at Google, but  not for the Assistant team.**